# How to map array of elements inside the marquee tag in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display array of elements one by one in marquee.
How to map array of elements inside the marquee in the react

Comment: show code please, there's literally nothing to go off of here. Like what is a Marquee?

Comment: marquee is a deprecated/obsolete html element nobody should use anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: btw, I'm pretty sure `<marquee>` does not exists in React-Native

Comment: ok , instead of marquee what i want to use for sliding the text in react.

Comment: Instead i want to display the array of data also , so i want to sliding the array of data, which package is statisfies both the condition

Answer (score 0):

In the react you can map the array of the elements one by one using the Array.prototype.map method like this:

```
    render() {
       return (
         <marquee>
           {theArray.map(theElement => theElement.toString())}
         </marquee>
       );
    }
```

of course you can change `theElement.toString()` to whatever you prefer

as a side note, marquee is a deprecated/obsolete html element and you should avoid using it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee